# New Salesforce Mobile App not showing up on iOS

Tags: salesforce-mobile-app

My understanding from the [Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_mobile_app_new_welcome.htm) is, that the new Salesforce Mobile App Experience is shown up automatically for every user. Unfortunately it does not nor did I find any way to enable it. The Salesforce App (iPad) is the latest from the App Store. When I authenticate against a Scratch Org it does display the new experience. But when I authenticate against a partial sandbox or production org it always shows the old one. We tested on two different devices so the issue must be tight to the org.

[image]
[image]

Any ideas how I can enable the new Salesforce App or what prevents the new App from showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to the Salesforce support the following is status quo:

- the new Salesforce app experience is automatically shown on **phones** only - a tablet is not treated as a mobile
- if you haven't opt in during the last release to enable the new Salesforce app for **tablets** there is currently no way to use the new experience (see [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352373&type=1&mode=1))
- consider using mobil browsers on iPad instead (see [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_ipad_browser.htm&type=5))

Answer (score 1):

After going through the [help docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_app_requirements.htm&type=5), I found this:-

### Salesforce Mobile App Updates

Customers whose devices meet current minimum platform requirements are eligible to receive Salesforce mobile app feature updates and fixes.

**Salesforce Mobile App for Android and iOS**

1. Enhanced features and functionality are provided in major version
   updates.Salesforce aim to release a new major version of the
   Salesforce mobile app for Android and iOS after the completion of
   each Salesforce major release to all production instances.
2. The timeframe in which a new major version is released varies and
   can be affected by factors outside of Saleforce’s control, including
   new requirements from Apple or Google or changes to the iOS or
   Android operating systems.
3. Customers can install new major and bug fix versions from the App Store and Google Play as long as their mobile devices meet Salesforce’s current minimum mobile operating system requirements. If a device is running an older operating system, updated versions of the Salesforce mobile app don’t appear in Google Play or the App Store.

Comment: Thank you Sanket for the link and further information. Our devices meet the minimum requirements and I can proof that it is not a general iOS or device issue as the new Mobile App shows up when authenticated against a Scratch Org. Any further ideas?